# Django static files outside app not loading

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-1.9

My static files will load fine if they are located inside the app but if they are located outside the app like in my project directory they will not load. I know this seems to be a question asked a million times but I can't see what to change with my code. This is Django 1.9

**folder structure**

```
/site
├── manage.py
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── css
│   │       ├── fonts
│   │       ├── img
│   │       ├── libs
│   │       └── scripts
│   ├── templates
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── app1
├── app2
└── app3
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rooms',
    'events',
    'activities',
] 

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

**index.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "main/css/bootstrap.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "main/libs/animate.min.css" %}">
```

Comment: I think there is a spelling mistake. It should be `STATICFILES_DIRS` not `STATICFILES_DIR`

Comment: @python That spelling doesn't seem to matter either way. I tested both. Thank you though

Comment: @python I was mistaken, it did need to be `STATICFILES_DIRS` but I also forgot the comma after `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` Thanks again!

Comment: I have added the answer. Please accept it if it was helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a spelling mistake. It should be `STATICFILES_DIRS` not `STATICFILES_DIR`

Comment: Thanks for this. Had a lot of difficulty in getting this to work, mainly because `STATICFILES_DIRS` needs to be spelled exactly. I also had another error `The STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list` - which is resolved by adding `[]` around the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You placed your static directory in your project folder, if you want it to be there (although not the right way) you should change the:

`STATICFILES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`

to:

`STATICFILES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "project/static")`

** I think it's better to place your static folder outside of project folder ( if you want to use global static files) **

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on not putting the static files in project folder. I want these file to be global though so I moved them up to the site root. Unfortunately, after making that change I still don't get my static files to load.